# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit' / PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

Мне нужно сделать мини браузер но Python не видит ни `PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets`, ни `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets`.

Comment: WebKit только для Qt4 доступен, в Qt5 QWebEngine используется (вроде бы, основанным на хрониуме)

Answer (score 2):

Его нужно поставьте отдельно:
Python 2.7:

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Python 3.x:

```
pip3 install PyQtWebEngine
```